# how to set Check Repository radio group in gridcontrol devexpress using C# from value another table

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

i have repository radio group in grid control cell, i wanna set checked in repository radio while value from another cell. this my sample:

[image]

while **ISJAWAB** value is **1**, repository radio group will be checked in column **PILIH**.

i have tried simple code but it doesn't work:

```
private void gridView2_CustomDrawCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "PILIH")
    {
        var val = Convert.ToString(gridView2.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "ISJAWAB"));
        if (val == "1")
        {
            e.DisplayText = "1"; //nilai 1 untuk select radio
        }
    }
}
```

in the repository collection i have set value to **1**, and it automatically set check in repository radio group.

[image]

need help ??

Comment: First question is why do you use radio buttons and not check boxes? Second - what method is your code placed in - something line `gridView_CustomUnboundColumnData`? What's for sure is that you should use not `e.DisplayText = "1"` but something like `e.Value = true`. Not sure how it will behave for radio buttons though.

Comment: In your case you must set in type of your repository value =string,but i suggest to use check box

Comment: why did i choose radio? because that grid allow user just select one option no more,..if i use check user can multiple check in that value and don't wanna it

Comment: @DmitryRotay i have update my code above,.. i place the event `gridView2_CustomDrawCell`

Comment: @aminvincent do you use radio buttons only for display purpose? I mean, will users click them to choose a row and change `"ISJAWAB"` column value?

Comment: it just display purpose only,.. when i have value in "ISJAWAB" radio will check

Comment: Please check my answer below. We can discuss it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RadioGroup` is not the best choice for the in-place editor in this case, as it gives you redundant functionality to display several choices within single cell. For your purpose you can use `CheckEdit`. Also, with `CustomDrawCell` event you will have to actually manually redraw your radio buttons. There's an easier solution utilizing unbound columns.

So I suggest the following solution:

1.Add `CheckEdit` repository item, set it's `CheckStyle` property equal to `Radio`.

2.Make your `PILIH` column's `Unbound Type = Boolean`. Assign above mentioned `CheckEdit` repository item to it's `ColumnEdit`. Set `OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false`.

3.Add `gridView2.CustomUnboundColumnData` event handler with body like following:

```
private void gridView2_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsGetData && e.Column.FieldName == "PILIH")
    {
        var row = (DataRow) e.Row;
        var val = Convert.ToString(row["ISJAWAB"]));
        if (val == "1")
        {
            e.Value = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if i use `e.RowHandle` this in `CustomUnboundColumnData` didn't recognized why? i have try change my radio group to be checkedit and change style to be radio

Comment: Oh, I've used an old version for my example. I'll update it. What kind of data source do you use? DataTables or something else?

Comment: Ok, I've updated the example for the case if you use DataTable as a data source. You can modify it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

you must change the type of reposityRadio to Boolean to true instead of 1 :

[image]

2nd the PILIH column data source must be type bool
and use this code :

```
private void gridView2_CustomDrawCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "PILIH")
    {
        var val = Convert.ToString(gridView2.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "ISJAWAB"));
        if (val == "1")
        {
            gridView2.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "PILIH", true);
        }
    }
}
```

the result should be like this :

[image]

Comment: i try use your coding suggest, when i run it my column "PILIH" still doesn't checked